# Resizing a Image to selection rectangle Delphi

Tags: image, delphi, firemonkey

Hi i cant figure out why this wont work.
I have a image and a selection and i want the image to always be the same size and position as the selection so i put this code in a timer:

```
  procedure TfrmMainUI.tmrUpdateTimer(Sender: TObject);
  var i : integer; 
  begin
    Image1.Width:=Selection1.Width;
    Image1.Height:=Selection1.Height;
    Image1.Position.X:=Selection1.Position.X;
    Image1.Position.Y:=Selection1.Position.Y;
  end;
```

But it doesn't work.

What is supposed to happen is the image resizes to the selection and its position also follows the selection.
But what happens is that i can move and resize the selection and the image just stays where it is and doesn't resize.

[image: Image stays where it is]

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? We can't see your screen or read your mind. "it doesn't work" might be clear to you, but we can't read your mind or see your screen from here. You need to explain what the problem is you're trying to solve if you want us to help you.

Comment: That code looks fine, so you'll have to explain more about what is not happening. I would, however, recommend hanging the event of TSelection.OnTrack which will be called immediately when the selection is changed rather than waiting for a timer to tick.

Comment: Does the selection act (presumably mouse down, mouse move) run a modal message loop? In which case your timer won't fire.

Comment: And yes, "it doesn't work" is hopeless for us. We've no idea what that means. Try to imagine yourself in our position. We don't know what you expect, we cannot see your screen.

Comment: I edited the question. Sorry for being vague.

Comment: @David: I suppose `TImage.Position` is something that happened after Delphi 2009?

Comment: @David: Yeah, thought so. Need to catch up some day...

Comment: @Andreas Wait until FMX is past alpha stage, say 2020.

Comment: So does anyone have any theory's on why this isn't working.

Comment: I presume you moved your code into `OnTrack` as Mike suggested. What happened when you did that?

Comment: It worked like a charm but the thing is i am creating the selection and images at runtime so they dont have events like a placed object would have how can i do it with selections that i created at runtime?

Comment: @mikesutton your suggestion worked, but now i dont have image1 and selection1 anymore. I now have arrays of type Tselection and Timage that i need to resize together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mike Sutton pointed out in the comments, you should be using the `OnTrack` event of `TSelection` to trigger updates to your image.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Objects.TSelection.OnTrack) says:

> The event handler of the OnTrack event is called cyclically from the
>   MouseMove method while the TSelection object is in the process of
>   moving or resizing.
>
> Write a custom OnTrack event handler to perform a specific action when
>   TSelection is in the process of moving or resizing.

You state in a comment, the components are created dynamically at runtime, rather than on the designtime surface. So you will also need to assign your handler in code. Do it like this:

```
Selection1.OnTrack := SelectionTrack;
```

Your event handler will look like this:

```
procedure TfrmMainUI.SelectionTrack(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Image1.Width:=Selection1.Width;
  Image1.Height:=Selection1.Height;
  Image1.Position.X:=Selection1.Position.X;
  Image1.Position.Y:=Selection1.Position.Y;
end;
```

You also say in the comments that you need to track selection changes for a number of linked images and selections. You can modify the event handler like this:

```
procedure TfrmMainUI.SelectionTrack(Sender: TObject);
var
  Selection: TSelection;
  Image: TImage;
begin
  Selection := Sender as TSelection;
  Image := ImageFromSelection(Selection);//you need to implement this function
  Image.Width:=Selection.Width;
  Image.Height:=Selection.Height;
  Image.Position.X:=Selection.Position.X;
  Image.Position.Y:=Selection.Position.Y;
end;
```

Comment: @kobus I added something about your need to work with arrays of linked images/selections. I hope I understood right.

Comment: What would the ImageFromSelection function do ?

Comment: Good. My assumption is that you have a one-to-one relationship between selections and images. But I am guessing somewhat at this point!

Comment: Correct the selections are linked to the images.

Comment: I hate to ask but would you mind including the code for the ImageFromSelection function.

Comment: Well I can't yet. Because I don't know how you are storing your images and selections? I would store them like this. `TImageSelection = record Image: TImage; Selection: TSelection`. And then I would have an array of those, `TArray<TImageSelection>`. And then I would simply loop through the array looking for the specified `Selection`. When you find it, return the matching `Image`.

Comment: I am storing them in 2 separate arrays named arrImages and arrSelrect. If you could help it would be awesome.

Comment: Just run a for loop over `arrSelrect`. When you find the specified selection just return the matching image, the one in `arrImages` with the same index. But you would be much better off with my data structure. Since they are linked together, express that with a record.

Comment: If you get stuck, ask another question.

Comment: Ok well ill see what i can do.

Comment: Another option would be to reference the Image in the Selection's TagObject property, then you can cast it out again Image := Selection.TagObject as TImage.

Comment: Also, if you're only displaying one selection at a time then you only need on TSelection and you can have a CurrentImage or CurrentImageIndex property.